# Is there a term for fixation OR loss of an allele?

Tags: terminology, population-genetics

I remember reading a paper which used a term to describe either fixation OR loss of an allele via drift. Its definition is basically "the removal/fixation of a polymorphism in a population due to the action of genetic drift". An example of how it could be used in a sentence is:

> The expected time to *term* is dependent on the effective population size of the population, $N_e$.

I can't for the life of me remember the term, or the paper, and it doesn't appear to be common in the literature as I haven't encountered it again. It's driving me insane! Does anyone know what this term might be?

Comment: It seems like “equilibrium” may work, though that is likely more general than the term you are looking for.

Comment: Also, I've heard "extinction or fixation" used in this context, re: *The expected time to extinction or fixation is dependent on the effective population size of the population...*